# strongly connected components with stl c++ bug?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a file that contains a directed graph. Graph vertices are labeled from 1 to N with N close to 800.000 (thousands). My cointainers are:

```
vector<long> isExplored;
vector<long> f;
vector<vector<long>> matrix;
vector<vector<long>> matrixInverse;
```

My file function to read the file and set the vectors is(vector[0] is always     zero, that is the containers have size n+1):

```
void InputClass::readFile() {
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(fileName);
    string line;
    string word;
    int vertexNumber = 0;
    while(getline(inputFile, line)) {
        istringstream inputStream(line);
        inputStream >> word;
        if(vertexNumber != stoi(word)) {
            vertexNumber = stoi(word);
            matrix.resize(vertexNumber + 1);
        }
        while(inputStream >> word) {
            if(matrix[vertexNumber].size() == 0) {
                matrix[vertexNumber].push_back(0);
            }
            matrix[vertexNumber].push_back(stoi(word));
        }
    }
    long size = matrix.size();
    isExplored.resize(size);
    f.resize(size);
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        isExplored.push_back(false);
        f.push_back(0);
    }
    cout << "done";
}
My dfs algorithm is:

 void dfs(long vertex, InputClass kostas) {
     isExplored[vertex] = true;
     cout << "vertex: " << vertex;                                     //1
     for(unsigned long i = 1; i < kostas.matrix[vertex].size(); i++) {
        cout << " i: " << i << endl;
        if(!isExplored[kostas.matrix[vertex].at(i)]) {
            cout << "done1" << endl;
            dfs(kostas.matrix[vertex].at(i), kostas);
            cout << "done2" << endl;
        }
     }
     t++;
     f[vertex] = t;
 }
```

And finally the dfs loop:

```
void dfsLoop(InputClass kostas) {
    t = 0;
    for(unsigned long i = kostas.matrix.size() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        if(!isExplored[i]) {
            dfs(i, kostas);
            cout << "done" << " t " << endl;
    }
    //more code here
}
```

My program crashes at i = kostas.matrix.size() - 1 after some(i think 5) dfs recursive calls. The crash happens on the dfs call and //1 is never printed. I have checked the vector but they are intialized fine. Since //1 is never printed my guess is that the crash happens on function's variables long vertex or InputClass kostas. Kostas should be fine and my guess is that long vertex causes the error. Any suggestions? I must also mention that the algorithm works wihout a problem on small/medium inputs.

Comment: To the person who downvoted the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes he could at least be polite and give a reason.

Comment: Not I (downvote). I have a question for you, however. Out of the 639999200000 possible edges your graph may have, how many do you *actually* have. Besides passing by-reference mentioned below, is a map-algorithm possibly warranted? Just something worth considering, along with using an iterator approach (consider what `unsigned long i = kostas.matrix.size() - 1;` starts out at when someone sneaks in an empty file).

Comment: To avoid sneaking on an empty file you can always throw an exception. I have not counted the edges, but that would be an easy task to do considering that the graph is directed. Just add the components of matrix[i].size() - 1 all together. What do you mean by map algorithm possibly warranted? Btw i have checked the matrices.

Comment: Just a thought; nothing more. only using storage for what you use has benefit. I'd still pursue an iterator approach, however. Honestly I was just glad to see `getline` rather than `.eof` in that while-loop (been that kinda of day). Best of luck, sir.

Comment: Hahaha! For the iterator part you are right. Btw since the file is to large it would be wise to read the file in chuncks of memory with a use of a buffer rather than line by line. That would speed up the processs. Thanks for your comment, have a nice day!

Comment: @KostasRim "why does this crash" questions should contain a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I would edit the post but it is answered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you are copying the InputClass every time you make a call to dfs. Try passing it by reference by changing the method to `void dfs(long vertex, InputClass &kostas)` and the method call to `dfs(i, kostas);`

Comment: Um, no, No `&` in the call. It's for pointers, not references.

Comment: On the method call & is not needed. Anyway i am checking it right now... Class objects are not passed by reference? And why the downvote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote. And Class objects are not passed by reference, no. Not unless explicitly stated.

Comment: wow i somehow missed this, one momment i am checking it.  Lastly is this question off topic?

Comment: Hello again, i get a stack overflow error but this time it iterates on more vertices. The only thing i have in stack are the 2 matrices(which are only the variable name, the value is on the heap) but the error pops after some iterations of the for loop. Can you plz check it ? I edited the code. It seems that dfs function overflows the stack? I also did change the stack size from 1mb to 4000 and it still overflows...

Comment: @KostasRim: Don't change the question after it's answered.

Comment: Redited back to the first question, sorry for the trouble